# Images don't display in device but in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an array:

```
langArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Italiano",@"English",@"Francais", nil];`
```

and cell image like this :

```
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"language_%@_disabled.png",[langArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

but images don's display in device, in simulator they display normally.

Comment: Try clean the project and see if they still display in simulator ?

Comment: Reset the simulator as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the images name in your Xcode Project..

Because simulator is Case **Insensitive** and Device is Case **Sensitive**..

Answer (score 2):

May be the ImageName in your array different Imagename in your local. You can check upcapercase

Answer (score 1):

> Check in your Xcode project source may be your image extension is
>   **".PNG"** rathere then **".png"**